# Postgres building an index concurrently

Tags: postgresql

I'm reading this from the Postgres docs:

> Building Indexes Concurrently
>
> ...
> PostgreSQL supports building indexes without locking out writes. This
> method is invoked by specifying the CONCURRENTLY option of CREATE
> INDEX. When this option is used, PostgreSQL must perform two scans of
> the table, and in addition it must wait for all existing transactions
> that could potentially modify or use the index to terminate. Thus this
> method requires more total work than a standard index build and takes
> significantly longer to complete. However, since it allows normal
> operations to continue while the index is built, this method is useful
> for adding new indexes in a production environment....
>
> In a concurrent index build, the index is actually entered into the
> system catalogs in one transaction, then two table scans occur in two
> more transactions. Before each table scan, the index build must wait
> for existing transactions that have modified the table to terminate.
> After the second scan, the index build must wait for any transactions
> that have a snapshot (see Chapter 13) predating the second scan to
> terminate. Then finally the index can be marked ready for use, and the
> CREATE INDEX command terminates. Even then, however, the index may not
> be immediately usable for queries: in the worst case, it cannot be
> used as long as transactions exist that predate the start of the index
> build.

What is a system catalog? What is a table scan? So it sounds like the index is build first, then it must wait for existing transactions (ones that occurred during the index build?) to terminate, and then wait for any transactions that have a snapshot predating the second scan to terminate (what does this mean? How does it differ from the first statement). What are these scans?

Comment: a system catalog is a table that stores information about the database: tables,columns,types,keys, etc. *meta information*, so to say . A table scan is reading a table from top to bottom (and possibly doing something with whatever is encoutered)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What is a system catalog? - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html
2. What is a table scan? - It reads table to get values of a column you build index on.
3. ones that occurred during the index build? - no, ones that could change data after first table scan
4. what does this mean? It means it waits transactions to end.
5. What are these scans? First scan reads table before starting to build index concurrently. Allowing changes to table to avoid lock. When build is done it scans roughly saying a difference, apply a short lock and mark index as usable. It is different from `create index` in a way the last locks table, not permitting any changes to data, while `concurrently` scans twice, but alows changing data while building index

Comment: so I guess it needs to make a table scan in order to build the index? Also, what are transactions that could change data after first table scan that were not issued during the first table scan?

Comment: yes. imagine sequence in time: 1. user a types `create index concurently...` and preses enter, 2. user b inserts a row to a table. that new row was not in table at the moment user a started building index. this is the example of such transaction

Comment: @Jwan622 did I answer your question?

Comment: So when I wrote... '3. ones that occurred during the index build' and you said, no, ones that could change data after first table scan/ones that were attempted to insert a row to a table after I pressed enter... what's the difference? Isn't that what I said?

Comment: yes it was. did I answer rest of your questions? So If I edit N3 you will accept it?..